# Faster way to do a correspondence replace operation in python?

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, dictionary, merge

I am not sure I'm using the right term for this---I'd call this a merge operation maybe?  Simple matching?

I have two dictionaries.  One of them contains a list of tag IDs.  The other one is a correspondence between tag IDs and tag ID names.  I want to match the IDs and include the tag names in the first dict.

So, first dictionary looks like this:

```
>>> myjson
[
{"tags" : ["1","3"],"otherdata" : "blah"},
{"tags" : ["2","4"],"otherdata" : "blah blah"}
]
```

Second dictionary looks like this:

```
>>> tagnames
[
{"id": "1", "name":"bassoon"},
{"id": "2", "name":"banjo"},
{"id": "3", "name":"paw paw"},
{"id": "4", "name":"foxes"}
]
```

To replace the tag IDs in myjson with the tag ID names, I am currently doing this:

```
data = []
for j in myjson:
    d = j
    d['tagnames'] = [i['name'] for i in tagnames for y in d['tags'] if y==i['id']]
    data.append(d)
```

My desired output is this:

```
>>> data
[
{"tags" : ["1","3"],"otherdata" : "blah", "tagname" : ["bassoon","paw paw"]},
{"tags" : ["2","4"],"otherdata" : "blah blah", "tagname": ["banjo","foxes"]}
]
```

I'm getting the right output, but it seems really slow.  I get that it's doing full iterations of each element in myjson x full iterations of each element in tagnames (is that m x n? n x n?) every time and that that will be slow, but maybe there is a smarter syntax or tricks for speeding it up?  Walk the array just once instead of n times?

Oooh, also, would be cool if someone could suggest a way to do this assignment with a slick map or functional approach rather than the outer forloop.

Comment: `d['tagnames']` already changes the `myjson` structure *in place*. there is no need to create a new list `data` as well. `d = j` just assigns a reference, the dictionary is **not** copied.

Comment: Whoa, really?  Yikes.  OK, well, that should start the speedup, but worries me about messing up my old data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to transform your tagnames list into a dictionary:

```
tagnames_map = {t['id']: t['name'] for t in tagnames}
```

Now you can find matching tagnames much faster; your code already just made in-place changes, so I'll simplify it to:

```
for d in myjson:
    d['tagnames'] = [tagnames_map[t] for t in tagnames_map.viewkeys() & d['tags']]
```

The [`dict.viewkeys()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewkeys) returns a [dictionary view object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) which acts like a set. We intersect that set against your list of tags, resulting in a sequence of tags that are all listed in `tagnames_map`. By doing this we don't have to worry about any tags that are missing from the map.

If you are using Python 3, then you just use `tagnames_map.keys()` directly; in Python 3 the `.keys()`, `.values()` and `items()` methods have been changed to always return dictionary view objects.

If you wanted to make a copy instead, do so using `d.copy()`:

```
data = []
for d in myjson:
    d = d.copy()
    d['tagnames'] = [tagnames_map[t] for t in tagnames_map.viewkeys() & d['tags']]
    data.append(d)
```

[`dict.copy()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.copy) creates a shallow copy; mutable values are not copied, the new dict will just reference the same values. As you are not altering values here that is fine.

Running this against your sample input gives:

```
>>> pprint(data)
[{'otherdata': 'blah', 'tagnames': ['bassoon', 'paw paw'], 'tags': ['1', '3']},
 {'otherdata': 'blah blah',
  'tagnames': ['banjo', 'foxes'],
  'tags': ['2', '4']}]
```

Comment: That's super helpful and very clear.  I started running this and for my actual sample, it's still pretty slow---but I'm sure much faster than my original, which didn't even complete on my real sample.  Slowness here just the nature of the beast?

Comment: @Mittenchops: If your input data set is *huge* then yes, slowness is a function of the amount of data you are putting in. But the `tagnames` generation is locally fast (O(N)) instead of O(MN), with `N` the length of the `tags` list in each entry and `M` the length of the `tagnames` list).

Comment: @Mittenchops: if you can avoid making copies of all the entries then that'd be better still.

Comment: Yeah, as soon as you pointed out that that was redundant I started going back and modifying...all...of my scripts.  =)  Thanks.  I think it's just that the dataset is pretty huge.  It's half a million in myjson and 40k in tags, and has been running for about 20 min so far.

Comment: @Mittenchops: You are now creating 500.000 dictionary copies. For each copy, you'll be doing N dictionary lookups to map tags to tag names, where N is the length of the `tags` list. That is still a lot better than looping over N * 40.000 tag names *for each of the 500.000 entries*. You basically sped up the process by a factor of 40k.